# olap cube - развертка возвращает ошибку

Tags: sql-server, olap

Так как слаб в создании кубов:
Нужно из 4 таблиц создать куб. Все бы нечего, но при старте развертывания и обработки возникает ошибка:

```
Ошибки и предупреждения из ответа
    Внутренняя ошибка: Операция завершена неудачно.
    Ошибка OLE DB: Ошибка OLE DB или ODBC : При входе в систему пользователя "NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService" произошла ошибка.; 28000.
    Ошибки в реляционном модуле высокого уровня. Не удалось подключиться к источнику данных с DataSourceID "Test Cube" и Name "Test Cube".
    Ошибки модуля хранения OLAP: При обработке dimension с идентификатором "Questions" и именем "Questions" произошла ошибка.
    Ошибки модуля хранения OLAP: Ошибка при обработке атрибута "Questionname" измерения "Questions" из базы данных "MultidimensionalProject1".
    Сервер: Текущая операция отменена, поскольку другая операция в данной транзакции завершилась ошибкой.
    Ошибка OLE DB: Ошибка OLE DB или ODBC : При входе в систему пользователя "NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService" произошла ошибка.; 28000.
    Ошибки в реляционном модуле высокого уровня. Не удалось подключиться к источнику данных с DataSourceID "Test Cube" и Name "Test Cube".
    Ошибки модуля хранения OLAP: При обработке dimension с идентификатором "Questions" и именем "Questions" произошла ошибка.
    Ошибки модуля хранения OLAP: Ошибка при обработке атрибута "Groupname" измерения "Questions" из базы данных "MultidimensionalProject1".
```

что может быть не так?

**Изменение 1:**
Ошибка:

```
Ошибки и предупреждения из ответа
    Внутренняя ошибка: Операция завершена неудачно.
    Источник данных "Test Cube" содержит значение ImpersonationMode, которое не поддерживается для операций обработки.
    Ошибки в реляционном модуле высокого уровня. Не удалось подключиться к источнику данных с DataSourceID "Test Cube" и Name "Test Cube".
    Ошибки модуля хранения OLAP: При обработке dimension с идентификатором "Questions" и именем "Questions" произошла ошибка.
    Ошибки модуля хранения OLAP: Ошибка при обработке атрибута "Questionname" измерения "Questions" из базы данных "MultidimensionalProject1".
    Источник данных "Test Cube" содержит значение ImpersonationMode, которое не поддерживается для операций обработки.
    Ошибки в реляционном модуле высокого уровня. Не удалось подключиться к источнику данных с DataSourceID "Test Cube" и Name "Test Cube".
    Ошибки модуля хранения OLAP: При обработке dimension с идентификатором "Questions" и именем "Questions" произошла ошибка.
    Ошибки модуля хранения OLAP: Ошибка при обработке атрибута "Groupname" измерения "Questions" из базы данных "MultidimensionalProject1".
    Сервер: Текущая операция отменена, поскольку другая операция в данной транзакции завершилась ошибкой.
```

Comment: В истрчнике данных поставьте чекрыжик на текущего виндового пользователя, вбейте логин, пароль.

Comment: @Kawalski, я сделал, но ошибка осталась